# Locate languages in the arithmetic hierarchy

Tags: computability

I'm finding it difficult to locate the languages $L_1$ and $L_2$ in the arithmetic hierarchy. If anyone could explain which class they're in an why that would be great. Thanks in advance.

$L_1$ = {$<w,v>$ : exist u s.t. $|u| > |v|$, accepted by the Turing Machine $M_w$}

$L_2$ = {$<w,v>$ : $M_w$ accepts all string of size $> 2|v|$}

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2506443/14578, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/83478/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.